# How to display string in a listbox using C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, listbox

I am trying to extract the content of a .txt file and then display it in a listbox, my developing environment is VC++ 2010.

listBox1,button1 are elements of my Windows form appliaction.

This is what i got so far:

```
         private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
          {
             ifstream ss_dfs_output("C:\\Users\\...\\Sampletext.txt");
             string TempStoreToDisp;
             vector<string> VecToDisp;
             vector<string>::iterator ToDisp_ptr;
             string OutToDisp;
             while (getline(ss_dfs_output,TempStoreToDisp,'\n'))
             {
                 VecToDisp.push_back(TempStoreToDisp);
             }
             for (ToDisp_ptr=VecToDisp.begin();ToDisp_ptr!=VecToDisp.end();ToDisp_ptr++)
             {
                 OutToDisp = *ToDisp_ptr;
                 String ^sss = Convert::ToString(OutToDisp.c_str());
                 this->listBox1->Items->Insert(0,sss);
             }
           }
```

The compiling was successfull but the output seems strange. Seems sss returns "true" but shoudn't it be a string?

Comment: why do you mix C++ and CLR? Why don't you do either C++/Win32/MFC or C#/Winforms ?

Comment: i use "String *sss = Convert::ToString(OutToDisp.c_str()); " orginally but it could not pass complier.   I am new to this so don't quite sure about the relationship inbetween them.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
this->listBox1->Items->Add(gcnew String(OutToDisp.c_str())); // you can still Insert if you want
```

[MSDN SByte* constructor reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s9t975.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this method but the following error comes out:

error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::ListBox::ObjectCollection::Add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String' to 'System::Object ^'

Comment: Problem solved.
Need to add "gcnew".
Hope this thread will help more ppl.


            this->listBox1->Items->Add(gcnew String(OutToDisp.c_str()));